# Problem with reply and cancel reply buttons in WordPress comments

Tags: javascript, wordpress

If the user clicks on the answer button, the hidden answer button and the cancel answer button will appear. If the user clicks on the cancel reply button, the hidden cancel reply button and the reply button will appear.

```
function customize_wp_footer() { ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ){
                $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
                $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
                $( '.comment-reply-link' ).hide();
            } );
                $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
                $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).hide();
                $( '.comment-reply-link' ).show();
            } );
        } );
    </script>
<?php } add_action( 'wp_footer', 'customize_wp_footer' );
```

But there is a problem, when I click on the reply button, the reply button of all comments is hidden, if I want to hide the reply button of the same comment. I need to look for a class or ID that is specific to the same comment.

```
<div id="comment-28" class="comment_container"></div>
```

I see that the ID of each comment is specific to the comment itself, How to call the ID of each comment and put it in the javascript code above? For example #comment-ID :

```
function customize_wp_footer() { ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ){
                $( '#comment-ID .comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
                $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
                $( '#comment-ID .comment-reply-link' ).hide();
            } );
                $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
                $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).hide();
                $( '#comment-ID .comment-reply-link' ).show();
            } );
        } );
    </script>
<?php } add_action( 'wp_footer', 'customize_wp_footer' );
```

My html code :

```
<div id="reviews" class="woocommerce-Reviews">
    <div id="comments">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-Reviews-title"></h2>
            <ol class="commentlist">
                <li class="review even thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-24">
                    <div id="comment-24" class="comment_container">
                        <div class="comment-text">
                            <p class="meta">
                                <img src="http://localhost/i/wp-content/uploads/avatar/11-32x32.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" class="avatar avatar-32 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-32 alignnone photo">
                                <strong class="woocommerce-review__author"></strong>
                                <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"></em>
                                <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime=""></time>
                            </p>
                            <div class="description"><p></p></div>
                            <div class="footer"><span class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-24" data-commentid="24" data-postid="745" data-belowelement="comment-24" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="" aria-label="">replay</a></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li><!-- #comment-## -->
                <li class="review odd alt thread-odd thread-alt depth-1" id="li-comment-25">
                    <div id="comment-25" class="comment_container">
                        <div class="comment-text">
                            <p class="meta">
                                <img src="http://localhost/i/wp-content/uploads/avatar/11-32x32.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" class="avatar avatar-32 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-32 alignnone photo">
                                <strong class="woocommerce-review__author"></strong>
                                <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"></em>
                                <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime=""></time>
                            </p>
                            <div class="description"><p></p></div>
                            <div class="footer"><span class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-24" data-commentid="24" data-postid="745" data-belowelement="comment-24" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="" aria-label="">replay</a></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor even depth-2" id="li-comment-28">
                            <div id="comment-28" class="comment_container">
                                <div class="comment-text">
                                    <p class="meta">
                                        <img src="http://localhost/i/wp-content/uploads/avatar/11-32x32.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" class="avatar avatar-32 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-32 alignnone photo">
                                        <strong class="woocommerce-review__author"></strong>
                                        <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"></em>
                                        <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime=""></time>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="description"><p></p></div>
                                    <div class="footer"><span class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-24" data-commentid="24" data-postid="745" data-belowelement="comment-24" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="" aria-label="">replay</a></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="children">
                                <li class="review odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-31">
                                    <div id="comment-31" class="comment_container"> 
                                        <div class="comment-text">
                                            <p class="meta">
                                                <img src="http://localhost/i/wp-content/uploads/avatar/11-32x32.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" class="avatar avatar-32 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-32 alignnone photo">
                                                <strong class="woocommerce-review__author"></strong>
                                                <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"></em>
                                                <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime=""></time>
                                            </p>
                                            <div class="description"><p></p></div>
                                            <div class="footer"><span class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-24" data-commentid="24" data-postid="745" data-belowelement="comment-24" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="" aria-label="">replay</a></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="children">
                                        <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor even depth-4" id="li-comment-32">
                                            <div id="comment-32" class="comment_container">
                                                <div class="comment-text">
                                                    <p class="meta">
                                                        <img src="http://localhost/i/wp-content/uploads/avatar/11-32x32.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" class="avatar avatar-32 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-32 alignnone photo">
                                                        <strong class="woocommerce-review__author"></strong>
                                                        <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"></em>
                                                        <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime=""></time>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <div class="description"><p></p></div>
                                                    <div class="footer"><span class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-24" data-commentid="24" data-postid="745" data-belowelement="comment-24" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="" aria-label="">replay</a></span></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="children">
                                                <li class="review odd alt depth-5" id="li-comment-33">
                                                    <div id="comment-33" class="comment_container">
                                                        <div class="comment-text">
                                                            <p class="meta">
                                                                <img src="http://localhost/i/wp-content/uploads/avatar/11-32x32.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" class="avatar avatar-32 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-32 alignnone photo">
                                                                <strong class="woocommerce-review__author"></strong>
                                                                <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"></em>
                                                                <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime=""></time>
                                                            </p>
                                                            <div class="description"><p></p></div>
                                                            <div class="footer"><span class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-24" data-commentid="24" data-postid="745" data-belowelement="comment-24" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="" aria-label="">replay</a></span></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <ul class="children">
                                                        <li class="review even depth-6" id="li-comment-375">
                                                            <div id="comment-375" class="comment_container">
                                                                <div class="comment-text">
                                                                    <p class="meta">
                                                                        <img src="http://localhost/i/wp-content/uploads/avatar/11-32x32.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="" class="avatar avatar-32 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-32 alignnone photo">
                                                                        <strong class="woocommerce-review__author"></strong>
                                                                        <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"></em>
                                                                        <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime=""></time>
                                                                    </p>
                                                                    <div class="description"><p></p></div>
                                                                    <div class="footer"><span class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-24" data-commentid="24" data-postid="745" data-belowelement="comment-24" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="" aria-label="">replay</a></span></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li><!-- #comment-## -->
                                                    </ul><!-- .children -->
                                                </li><!-- #comment-## -->
                                            </ul><!-- .children -->
                                        </li><!-- #comment-## -->
                                    </ul><!-- .children -->
                                </li><!-- #comment-## -->
                            </ul><!-- .children -->
                        </li><!-- #comment-## -->
                    </ul><!-- .children -->
                </li><!-- #comment-## -->
            </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="review_form_wrapper">
        <div id="review_form">
            <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">

            </div><!-- #respond -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

If you look at the picture, you can see that a parent must be selected who has both the comment and comment boxes with her children :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WO5c.png)

parent : `<li class="review odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-31">`

children : `<div id="comment-31" class="comment_container">` and `<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">`

Only `id="li-comment-31"` is specific to herself and is not used in other comments.

Is my thought correct? Because I don't have much knowledge about JavaScript؟

Comment: No, you should _not_ do this by selecting elements via ID. Make use of the relation these elements have to each other in the DOM. Go up to a common parent element - `.comment_container` would probably work in this situation - first, and then select only the reply link in there.

Comment: CBroe, thanks for the reply. `.comment_container` It is only the parent of the comment and not the parent of the comment submission form. I edited the question, put a picture, please see.

Comment: Well then chose whatever common parent element actually fits in this situation ...

Comment: CBroe, thanks for the reply. common parent : `<li class="review odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-31">`, All values ​​inside the class were used in other comments, only the value inside ID is specific to each comment, `li-comment-ID`.

Comment: So find the parent based on one of its characteristics then, like for example the `review` class. Why do you want to bring IDs into it again now?

Comment: CBroe, Thank you very much for the answer. `review` class is shared in depth 1, 2, 3 and 4, if I select it when I click on depth 1 response button, depth 2, 3 and 4 response button also disappear. Shouldn't I find a class or ID unique to the comment so that it only affects the same JavaScript comment? The only unique item that is specific to the comment itself is the `li-comment-ID`.

Comment: You are inserting `#cancel-comment-reply-link` after the `.comment-reply-link` element - they are both contained in `.footer` now, so you should not need to go up any further than this.

Comment: **CBroe**, I ran into another problem that I mentioned at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also traverse up the DOM from the reply button to the comment container and then find the `.comment-reply-link` and `#cancel-comment-reply-link` elements that are children of the same comment container, without using the comment's ID. Following code snippet should work -

```
function customize_wp_footer() { ?>
<script>
    jQuery( function( $ ){
        $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment-text');
            commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).show();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
        } );
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment-text');
            commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).hide();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').show();
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: 2 problems must be solved : 1) When the reply, for example depth 2, is clicked, the reply buttons of depths 3, 4, and 5 should not be hidden. 2) When the depth 1 comment reply button i.e. the main comment is clicked, the hidden reply button and the cancel button should appear.

Comment: If possible, please provide a sample HTML structure with your question. It's hard to picture the DOM tree from your jquery snippet.

Comment: The html output was placed in the question.

Comment: More explanation : 1 depth comments, reply and cancel reply buttons are displayed together as before, When I click on the comment reply button of depth 2, all the comment reply buttons of lower depths i.e. depth 3, 4 and 5 are hidden. But the answer button of other comments that do not have a parent-child relationship with this comment remains the answer button.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet based on your given HTML code. Let me know if it works!

Comment: When I click on the comment reply button, for example depth 2, both reply and cancel buttons are displayed together, exactly by default without javascript code. When I click on the cancel button, both the reply and cancel buttons disappear.

Answer (score 0):

**CBroe** and **Junaed Siam**, Thank you both very much for helping me. With a lot of effort and the help of both friends ( **CBroe** and **Junaed Siam** ), I was able to solve my problem :

```
function customize_wp_footer() { ?>
<script>
    jQuery( function( $ ){
        $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
            $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
        } );
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).hide();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').show();
        } );
    } );
</script>
<?php } add_action( 'wp_footer', 'customize_wp_footer' );
```

Comment: Another problem that caught my eye now, When I click the reply button and click the reply button to another comment without clicking the cancel button, the previous comment reply button disappears, what is the problem?